# encryption in Sql and decryption in asp.net (for querystring) possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, encryption

I have a sql job that sends email to all users everynight. It has a footer with Unsubscibe link which opens the asp.net page. As a querystring, i want to add encrypted EmailID to the link. so i can decrypt and use it to update the database.

How can i use encryption in sql and decrypt in asp.net? Is it possible or is there any other way?

Thanks a lot guys,
Remo

Comment: Try this http://nayyeri.net/how-to-encrypt-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net

Comment: FWIW encrypting query string parameters is security by obscurity and **generally worthless**.

Comment: Why go through the trouble of encryption/decryption when you are sending the user a link with their own email address in it? You could simply send the GUID for the row to be updated in the database instead, which would save considerable effort and net the same level of obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [EncryptByKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) and [DecryptByKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx) sql functions (sql-server 2008). In ASP you can always send query to db for decrypting purposes.